# Global function code does not work in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code on the book I`m reading:

```
>>> var=99
>>> def funct1():
    global var
    var+=1

>>> var
100
```

but when I try to run this code on my pc this happens:

```
>>> var=99
>>> def funct1():
    global var
    var+=1

>>> var
99
```

Does anyone know why this happens? My book is about Python 3.3 and after and I`m using Python version 3.8.3 so it should be ok...

Comment: You have to call the function: `funct1()`. Does the book show that?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the context of the book. But you should first call the function for var to change.

Like this:

```
var=99
>>> def funct1():
    global var
    var+=1

>>> funct1()
>>> var
100
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I completely forgot about it!